# How to convert it to string back?

Tags: c#

```
string result = string.Empty;
foreach (char ch in txt)
{
    result += Convert.ToString((int)ch, 10);
}
```

i've got this code, how do I get it back to a normal string?

Comment: What do you mean with "normal string"?

Comment: txt is a value of variable, might be any.

Comment: i just want to get the string that was converted like that back

Comment: txt is of course a `IEnumerable<char>` and it's likely a `char[]` or a `string`

Comment: I didn't get your question. Sorry. I am assuming txt is a string. You want to get the value of txt in result?

Comment: You can't do that. It is impossible.

Comment: txt should still have the original value, if that's a string. You did not ovewrite it.

Comment: What is the type of `txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible unless you are 100% sure all characters in `txt` are in the range 0-9, 10-99, 100-999, etc. (that is: the string representation of the integer value of each character has a fixed length)

Since you are not separating them, the results are ambiguous

## Update

As per the comments, you want to do some encryption and decryption. This is a **very weak** encryption method and I don't really recommend you to do this, but adding a delimiter could help you do this:

```
  public static string Encode(string txt)
  {
      string result = string.Empty;
      foreach (char ch in txt)
      {
          // "tku" will be our delimiter
          result += Convert.ToString((int)ch, 10) + "tku";;
      }
      result = result.Replace("0", "dos");
      result = result.Replace("1", "vso");
      result = result.Replace("2", "otw");
      result = result.Replace("3", "foa");
      result = result.Replace("4", "bae");
      result = result.Replace("5", "xgd");
      result = result.Replace("6", "ymt");
      result = result.Replace("7", "ksx");
      result = result.Replace("8", "wte");
      result = result.Replace("9", "rom");
      Console.WriteLine(result);
      return result;
    }

    public static string Decode(string txt)
    {
        string result = txt;
        result = result.Replace("dos", "0");
        result = result.Replace("vso", "1");
        result = result.Replace("otw", "2");
        result = result.Replace("foa", "3");
        result = result.Replace("bae", "4");
        result = result.Replace("xgd", "5");
        result = result.Replace("ymt", "6");
        result = result.Replace("ksx", "7");
        result = result.Replace("wte", "8");
        result = result.Replace("rom", "9");
        // "tku" will be converted to spaces
        result = result.Replace("tku", " ");
        string result2 = string.Empty;
        // and we split over them
        foreach(var res in result.Split(' '))
        {
          if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(res))
          {
            result2 += ((char)Int32.Parse(res)).ToString();
          }
        }           
        return result2;
    }
```

I've made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wEjzeX): https://dotnetfiddle.net/zV9zYw

Again, **I strongly recommend against this**, just put it to let you know how it works. I've not optimized the code or tried to make it any better than yours.

This encryption is **extremely** weak, and there are good two way encription engines built in the .NET framework.

PS: for readers, the code comes from OP's comments, [pasted here](http://pastebin.com/viPihQYk)

Comment: Besides the point that the txt variable is never being modified...

Comment: how do I get this working? I'd like to make an encrypter like that
http://pastebin.com/viPihQYk

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I'm assuming (which should be obvious) he only has access to `result` whenever he is trying to "reverse" it

Comment: @PiotrSawicki I recommend against trying to create encrypters and just use the ones that are already known to be secure. Jcl, yeah, I guess

Comment: @PiotrSawicki you could use a delimiter. Let me update

Comment: can u tell me if what he wants is that:

he receives "0123456" in string txt;

then he uses his function and it returns a completly diferent string result;

then he wants to get txt value from result value?

Comment: @RaphaelRibeiro basically, yes... he gets an arbitrary string, "encodes" it, then at some point he wants to decode it, having only the encoded string (not the original one)

Comment: if it is only numbers 0-9

can't he use this?

int cont = 0;
            string aux = String.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; )
            {

                while (cont < 2)
                {
                    aux += result[i];
                    i++;
                    cont++;
                }

                cont = 0;
                originaltxt += (Convert.ToInt32(aux) - 48);
                aux = String.Empty;
            }

Comment: @RaphaelRibeiro never does it say the input string is only numbers. In fact, it seems to be an .ini file as per the comments

Comment: ahh ok so, I thought it was only numbers, sry.